# How to create a dynamic list using Express, HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I need to make my list dynamic by taking the data from the JSON file I created, I need to make sure that when I click on an item in the list it then takes me to a specific item based on the id. I tried this way but it doesn't work, the list must be dynamic.

My API Express:

```
import express from "express";
import tours from "./tours_file/tours.json" assert { type: "json" };

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(
    "C:\\Users\\MartinaPangallo\\OneDrive - NEW TECHNOLOGY DEVELOPMENT ITALIA SRL\\Desktop\\sitoWebFE\\homepage.html"
  );
});

//----prendo tutti i tour

app.get("/tours", (req, res) => {
  res.json(tours);
});

//----Seleziono per id il mio tour

app.get("/tours/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const tour = tours.find((tour) => tour.id == id);
  res.json(tour);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The HTML and script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style></style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <style>
      .active {
        color: gainsboro;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .inactive {
        color: grey;
        font-weight: 100;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Homepage</h1>
    <p>scegli o aggiungi un tour</p>

    <div class="output"></div>
    <script>
      const output = document.querySelector(".output");
      const output1 = document.createElement("div");
      const url = "tours.json";
      const ul = document.createElement;
      output.append(output1);
      output.append(ul);

      window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        output.textContent = "ready";
        loadData();
      });

      function loadData() {
        fetch(url)
          .then((rep) => rep.json())
          .then((data) => {
            //   console.log(data);
            addToPage(data);
          });
      }

      function addToPage(arr) {
        arr.array.forEach((element) => {
          console.log(element);
          const li = document.createElement("li");
          li.textContent = el.name;
          if (el.status) {
            li.classList.add("active");
          } else {
            li.classList.add("inactive");
          }
          ul.append(li);
          li.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            li.classList.toggle("active");
            li.classList.toggle("inactive");
          });
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "The Forest Hiker",
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "country": "Trentino",
    "description": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "The Alpinist",
    "difficulty": "hard",
    "country": "Svizzera",
    "description": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "A Bicycle Trip",
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "country": "Sicilia",
    "description": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Horse Trip",
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "country": "Francia",
    "description": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
  }
]
```

I need help because I'm not sure where I'm wrong.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a specific situation. Can you please elaborate what it is doing right now and what exactly(!) it is supposed to do?

Comment: You situation is not clear at all, improve your question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are a living example based on your code [demo page url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-18wc7q?file=homepage.html)

there are these problems in your code, most of them are in your html-

1. fetch(url) and your `url` equals to `tours.json`. this is wrong, because you defined a endpoint in your express named `tours`, you can't ask the express for `tours.json`.
2. `const ul = document.createElement;` should be `const ul = document.createElement('ul');` you want use it to create a `ul`, not assign it to another variable
3. `arr.array.forEach((element)`  should be `arr.forEach((el)` , because arr will be the array,and `element` should be `el`, because you try to use `el` in the code below.
4. there are other small problem, i guess you can compare mine with yours.

---

Hope it helps

Comment: And also I think some javascript beginner tutorial will be useful for you.

Comment: thank you so much! but i have a question, how i can make this dynamic, now i take the json but if i want click on a element of the list an i want to see in another page the content? for example i click on The Forest Hiker and then i will see another page with the content of the selected tour?

Comment: @Martina if you want to go to another page, you should use [<a>](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: thank you so much, i modified this part of my code 
      function addToPage(arr) {
        arr.forEach((el) => {
          const li = document.createElement("li");
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          a.textContent = el.name;
          a.href = `/tours/${el.id}`;

          li.append(a);
          ul.append(li);
        });